# Selectively hide member of member of class

Tags: c++, include, friend

```
// PhysicalTraits.h
struct PhysicalTraits {
     unsigned int age; // years
     double height; // meters

     PhysicalTraits(const double H = 0.0, const unsigned int A = 0u) : age (A), height(H) {};
     ~PhysicalTraits() {};
};

// People.h
#include <PhysicalTraits.h>
class People {
    PhysicalTraits traits;

public:
    People(const double H = 0.0, const double A = 0u) : traits(H, A);
    ~People() {};

    void displayAge() { std::cout << "You are " << traits.age << " years old." << std::endl; }
    void displayHeight() { std::cout << "You are " << traits.height << " meters tall." << std::endl; }
};

// Me.h
#include <PhysicalTraits.h>
class Me {
    PhysicalTraits traits;

public:
    Me(const double H = 0.0) : traits(H);
    ~Me() {};

    void displayAge() {
        // I want `traits.age` to throw an error 
        std::cout << "You are " << traits.age << " years old." << 
    }
    void displayHeight() { 
        std::cout << "You are " << traits.height << " meters tall." << std::endl; 
    }
};
```

I intend to allow objects of type `People` to access `traits.age`. However, I don't want to know my age, so I want to restrict objects of type `Me` from accessing `traits.age`.

To do this, I modified `PhysicalTraits.h`:

```
#include <People.h>
struct PhysicalTraits {
    double height; // meters
private:
    unsigned int age; // years
    friend class People; // Objects of type `People` can access age
};
```

With `age` as a private member variable and as a friend with `People`, but not `Me`. I've solved the problem... kind of.

However, the *new* problem is that I've included `People.h` in `PhysicalTraits.h` and `PhysicalTraits.h` in `People.h`. So, when `PhysicalTraits.h` is compiled, before defining the `PhysicalTraits` object it will jump to the definition of the `People` object, which requires that the `PhysicalTraits` object is defined.

**How can I avoid this "mutual-include" problem while still ensuring that an object of type `Me` cannot access `traits.age`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to include `People.h` in `PhysicalTraits.h`. Full definition of class `People` is not required there. You can just declare that class.

`PhysicalTraits.h` would look like that:

```
class People;  // Forward declaration

struct PhysicalTraits {
    double height; // meters
private:
    unsigned int age; // years
    friend class People; // Objects of type `People` can access age
};
```

---

Forward declarations was created exactly in order to solve problems like yours (mutual-include). In c++ you code is (in general) parsed from top to bottom which creates a lot of problems when you need to use e.g. function which is defined after the call. Thats why declaration was implemented.
In your case compiler need to know only the name of the class, so declaration will suffice. However, you cannot create object of class which is only declared or call any of its methods.

It's also noteworthy that using declaration everywhere where it is possible speeds up the compilation because parsing a definition obviously takes some time.

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer. By any chance do you know why C++(XX/11) allows you to forward-declare a class like that? For whatever reason, in my mind it seems to challenge the notion that data must be strongly typed... (**NOTE:** Apologies for my "unsigned double" typo)

Comment: @VladislavMartin This is exactly to solve problems like yours (mutual-include). In c++ you code is (in general) parsed from top to bottom which creates a lot of problems when you need to use e.g. function which is defined after the call. Thats why declaration was implemented. In your case compiler need to know only the name of the class, so declaration will suffice. However, you cannot create object of class which is only declared or call any of its methods.

Comment: @VladislavMartin It's also noteworthy that using declaration everywhere where it is possible speeds up the compilation because parsing a definition obviously takes some time.

Comment: Ok, but only if you'll fix this typo in the question ;)